# Forwarding form data to specific port

Tags: html, forms, port, action

I have a form in HTML and I was hoping to use the action to POST the data to a specific site on a specific port where I would have a small program running that accepts and writes all incoming data on that port. Pretty much the app specifically waits for the form action and only listens on that port. I was hoping to avoid using PHP. Is this possible?

I guess I'm a little unclear on exactly how the form action actually sends data? There's a ton of resources for brief overviews out there on HTML form objects, but they mostly say hand off to PHP or use the data locally.

I've tried using a specific port in the action. E.g. http://www.example.com:1500 and then looking for incoming connections on that port to my router or webserver, but the browser gives me a site can't be reached and I don't see an attempted connection. I'm not even sure if this is possible though.

`<form method="POST" action="example.com:1500">`

I was hoping to get some sort of incoming attempted connection over the port I specified in the form, but I get nothing.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `https://` or `http://` (depending if the remote web application is TLS-encrypted or not) to the `action` attribute of your form, so it would look like this:

`<form method="POST" action="http://example.com:1500">`

Then, if the problem persists, you should check the communication between the servers:

- First, check the **source** web application (the one that is responsible for sending the form data). Make use of some packet capture and analysis tool, such as `tcpdump` or `Wireshark`, to see if there is an attempt of establishing a connection between the servers.
- If you see that the source application tried to communicate with the remote server and there is still no success at establishing a connection, do the same kind of packet analysis at the **receiving** end.

After that, you will probably have a better understanding of the issue. Then, you will be closer to attack its root cause, by trying to answer these questions:

- Is the remote server actually listening to connections at the specified port?
- Can there be a host firewall (such as `Windows Firewall` or `iptables`) on either server that is blocking such connections?
- Are there firewalls throughout the network that may be filtering these packets? Such firewalls might be dedicated or even built-in, such as within the border routers of either end of the connection.